# Azure search Indexer don't run

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, indexer

I have an azure search indexer but it stops running two days ago, when I try to run it immediately from Azure portal a notification **<<
Successfully started a run of indexer "name_indexer" >>** appears. but in the history this run doesn't appear, the same problem occurred again when I recreate a new Indexer!
what are the possible reasons for this ?

Comment: Can you possibly message me your indexer information, so I can take a look?  Are you sure that your indexer never actually ran?  There is a known issue with proper indexer progress updates in the portal, but I'm curious about the fact that you mentioned your indexer has stopped running per its schedule.

Comment: For the indexer that stops running  days ago :
Name of the indexer : indexer-demo
interval (minutes) : 900
History : no history since 30/04 , when I try to run it from the portal it say that the indexer successfully started a run but it is not the case.
I try also to create a new indexer but the same problem occured 
and It says that the indexer started a run but it didn't works (no history for this indexer )

Comment: Something did in fact seem to be wrong with your search service, but it should be resolved now.  In the future, you should file a support case for these types of issues and you should get a response much faster.